# Jquery ajax uploader with query string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used the following plugin for upload progress bar

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () { 
         $(".flupload").makeAsyncUploader({
        upload_url: "upload_logo_file.php?pid="+($(this).attr("id")), 
        flash_url: 'swfupload.swf',
        button_image_url: 'blankButton.png'
    });

    });
```

In my html form i used the floowing

```
<input type="file" id="1550" name="1550" class="flupload" />
<input type="file" id="1552" name="1552" class="flupload" />
```

The upload progress bar is working fine here. But my problem is: i want to pass the id (1550 or 1552) with the 'Upload_url' parameter.

For this used the following

```
upload_url: "upload_logo_file.php?pid="+($(this).attr("id")),
```

But the Id is not retrieved here while using ($(this).attr("id"))

How to get the current id here.

Please help.

Comment: your id's are invalid, they cannot begin with a digit. so try to change them first

Comment: ... or use `<input type="file" pid="1550" name="1550" class="flupload" />` instead (and get the `pid` value accordingly).

Comment: ok. I have changed the id with some other name as test_1550. But now also it is not retrieved.

Comment: every time you use `$(this).attr("id")` somebody should kick you

Answer (score 1):

Your ids are not valid html ids. Use a custom `data` attribute instead, like so:

```
<input type="file" data-id="1550" name="1550" class="flupload" />
```

and

```
upload_url: "upload_logo_file.php?pid="+$(this).data("id"),
```